# Is Meditation to relax shirk or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

Once I meditated with a YouTube video where a woman told me to relax with breathing exercises, but my intention was only to try it out and relax. I did not pray to the universe or say something like “ommm” like the Buddhists do. I tried to relax by shutting down some parts of my body (nervous system).

Did I commit shirk?

I already repented to Allah Subhanahu wa ta'ala and I'm frustrated that he won’t forgive me if it’s a sin.

Answer (score 0):

Shirk can be committed by acting against the three different categories.

- Rubūbīyah (Lordship of Allah)
- Al-Asma wa's-Sifat (names and attributes of Allah)
- Al-'Ibadah (worship of and supplication to Allah)

If someone gives lordship or attributes of Allah to others or worship/supplicate to others rather than Allah, then he has committed Shirk.